# zsh completion rules - remove file extension from completion result

Tags: zsh, filenames, autocomplete

I am trying to create simple zsh completion rules for a password manager script `pass`.

`pass` stores its passwords in directory structure, the files itself are `.gpg` files.

I want to complete directories and files in given path `$HOME/passwords`, so that directories names are simply completed, and file names are completed without `.gpg` extension

The following rules complete directory names correctly,

```
#compdef pass

_pass() {
    _arguments '1: :->directory'
    case $state in

    directory)
        _directories -W $HOME/passwords
    ;;

    esac
}
```

but it completes filenames by their full name, ie `foo.gpg`.

**How can I complete files without the `.gpg` extension ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is `_files -g '*.gpg(:r)'`: complete `*.gpg` files, but strip their extension while doing so, using the `r` [history modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) passed as a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). However this doesn't automatically insert a space after successful completions.

So call [`_path_files`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fpath_005ffiles) separately for directories and files to add the appropriate suffix (`/` or a space) explicitly with `-S` (which `_path_files` passes through to [`compadd`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#index-compadd).

```
_path_files -W $HOME/passwords -g '*(/)' -S /
_path_files -W $HOME/passwords -g '*.gpg(:r)' -S ' '
```

Comment: so where exactly should I add these two lines ? Inside `directory)` or should I add `file)` section ?

Comment: @400theCat Replace the call to `_directories` by this.